# Integration Test Started failing post Spring boot 2.2.0 upgrade with Swagger latest version 2.9.2 & HATEOS

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-hateoas

Integration Test Started failing post Spring boot 2.2.0 upgrade with Swagger latest version 2.9.2 & HATEOS

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'linkDiscoverers' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'linkDiscoverers' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer,
org.springframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but 
found 3: relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer, 
org.springframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: 
relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
```

Comment: for a moment disable your swagger by commening **@Configuration** and
'@EnableSwagger2** annotation

Comment: Build is successful now. Let me test Application as well. But need to check what is impact of removing this annotation

Comment: It was for test purpose to isolate, problem, the only impact is swagger will not work if you continue to go with current code.

Comment: Thanks For Your help, If you fine with then Please share linked-in or Twitter account.

Comment: posted my linkedin profile URL,

Comment: Wait... what is happening here? How did it help to disable swagger generation altogether, it was there for a purpose I am sure. And what is this linkedId profile sharing thingy? ‍♂️

Comment: Removing swagger is an tactical solutions until swagger ui configuration get fixed or compatible with spring boot 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with springfox may take while to resolve issue but there is alternative available with latest swagger v3 have similar capabilities of springfox

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi.git

Only disabled the SpringFox dependencies, added SpringDoc, and replaced the SpringFox bean, with a SpringDoc bean. Everything is working as expected. All I need to do is to convert a couple of annotations on each rest service so SpringDoc displays everything correctly. SpringDoc does work

Comment: Am not getting completely , can you some more details , am also facing the issue same

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it works for me

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency
```

Comment: Too me work, using this dependency.